# Recreate Complex JPG File As PSD? My Designer Disappeared

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I unfortunately hired someone who I thought was a fantastic, dependable designer. They created a very complex, extremely well put together landing page for me. They then sent me a jpg version of the landing page to review and suggest changes. Unfortunately for reasons unknown they have gone no contact for three weeks now and I am left with an incredible mockup but no PSD file. What is my best option to take this jpg and turn it into a PSD file or website? It does need some small tweaks but is pretty close to finished. Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: At the risk of muddying the water; if the designer disappeared, have you paid them for the mockup you've received? If not you should be very clear over whether usage rights have actually been transferred over to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you leave the mockup as-is and find a web developer to turn the mockup into a functioning website. There isn't much need for you to turn an almost completed design back into a Photoshop editable file if you're just trying to make a few tweaks. A mockup is not a completed project, you use this as a reference to gauge the overall design. So if a working website is the end result, then I would focus on that.

Comment: I also echo Andrew's advice. A competent front-end developer can use the JPEG to build out your site. The only reason to "need" a PSD is if there are complex graphic elements that need to be generated. And even there, a competent front-end developer should be able to recreate or generate such graphics.